# Win10: Change default folder optimization

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer

Using Windows 10, I prefer to treat all folders as "General Items" and use Detail view.  When I create a new folder containing only a few WAV files, the folder optimization automatically changes to "Music".  Similarly, if I create a folder containing a few video clips, it changes to "Videos".  How can I prevent this?

I'm not talking about libraries.  This affects even folders on a secondary hard drive.

[image]

Comment: Don't ya love it when Windows thinks for you......>>>>https://winaero.com/blog/disable-folder-type-discovery-windows-10/

Answer (score 2):

Here are a couple of `.bat` files that will do that.

**Reset_Folder_View_Settings_of_All_Folders_to_Default.bat**

```
@echo off
:: To reset folder view settings of all folders
Reg Delete "HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\BagMRU" /F
Reg Delete "HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags" /F
Reg Delete "HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\ShellNoRoam\Bags" /F
Reg Delete "HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\ShellNoRoam\BagMRU" /F
Reg Delete "HKCU\SOFTWARE\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\BagMRU" /F
Reg Delete "HKCU\SOFTWARE\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags" /F
Reg Delete "HKCU\SOFTWARE\Classes\Wow6432Node\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags" /F
Reg Delete "HKCU\SOFTWARE\Classes\Wow6432Node\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\BagMRU" /F

:: Reset "Apply to Folders" views to default
REG Delete "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Streams\Defaults" /F

:: Reset size of details, navigation, preview panes to default
Reg Delete "HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Modules\GlobalSettings\Sizer" /F

:: Kill and restart explorer
taskkill /f /im explorer.exe
start explorer.exe
```

**All_Folders_Use_General_Items_Folder_Template.bat**

```
@echo off
REG ADD "HKCU\SOFTWARE\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags\AllFolders\Shell" /V FolderType /T REG_SZ /D NotSpecified /F
:: Kill and restart explorer
taskkill /f /im explorer.exe
start explorer.exe
```

Source:
[How to Change the Template of a Drive, Folder, or Library in Windows 10](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/7923-change-folder-template-windows-10-a.html).

Comment: Thanks for that but when I did it, the positions of my icons on my desktop were reset (windows 10)

Comment: @MagTun: This happens on Windows. To recover from such problems you may use software such as [Iconoid](https://download.cnet.com/Iconoid-64-Bit/3000-2072_4-75784328.html) or [ReIcon](https://www.sordum.org/8366/reicon-v2-0-restore-desktop-icon-layouts/).